# Custom Splash Screen for iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, splash-screen

After some googling I found that messing with the default Xcode launch screen is not the most proper way for make ur splash screen wait for some time and other stuff so I add new view controller (custom class named splash) to my storyboard and then after 2 seconds it's will display my main `UINavigationController` and it's not working just freeze on the splash screen

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class splash: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(2.0)
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainmenu") as! UINavigationController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd reconsider using a splash screen altogether. Do you really want to make your user wait for 2 seconds before using your app just to show a bit of branding?

Comment: well, it's the customer requirement my friend

Comment: i'm totally agree with u , but at the same time the default splash screen is un useful at all its appear for less than a sec !

Comment: unfortunately my friend some times  u can't say no to the client :)

Comment: @Mriyadh that "splash screen" that you are talking about isn't a "splash screen" stop calling it a splash screen. It is a launch screen. Its sole purpose is to give the impression to the user that your app is loading instantly. The launch screen should resemble the first screen the app will show (without content) so when the app is opening it looks like it's loaded before it's even on screen. (Look at the maps app as an example). Why even have branding there at all? The user has already bought/downloaded the app. They know who's app it is. That's why they downloaded it.

Answer (score 2):

i have solve it using perform selector

```
class splash: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super . viewDidLoad()

    performSelector(#selector(splash.showmainmenu), withObject: nil, afterDelay: 2)
}

func showmainmenu(){

    performSegueWithIdentifier("mainmenu", sender: self)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do - is an ugly hack. **Don't**.

You should create your custom `Splash View Controller` with layout that mimics your default splash screen image, perform custom animations if any, and then push/present next view controller (on the main thread), or whatever you want to do according to your app requirements.